# Microsoft Graph API (office 365) updating only attendees of calendar events

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

If I am like to update a event on Microsoft Graph I send

```
PATCH
/me/calendars/[CalendarId]/events
```

With the whole event-information just to update one or two attendee(s).

Is there a better way to add or remove a attendee?

At the moment I have events with 300 to 400 attendees. By updating more than 100 events it ends up with a 439-response. Because: Every calendar-event sends a mail to each attendee, but there is a limit of 10k mails every 24h each office365-account can send. By updating the whole event, the Microsoft API sends this mails to everyone – even if the recipient does not notice, because office does not show this mails if there is no change for the attendee who’s already invited. (There is no change for the most attendees)

Comment: Please remove the "php" tag from that question - or explain the connection to PHP,

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no now. Because the event have been sent to all attendees(300 to 400 in your case), so if you remove one requirement/optional attendee, outlook will update notification to other attendee.

The best UX is you just add the needed attendee while create the Event.

And if you still want the feature, just vote up the existing feature request in [User Voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) or submit a new one.